# Linq to XElement, multiple parameters

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am creating an `XElement` object and have problems adding multiple elements to a node using Linq.

There's a list of objects with multiple properties:

```
class Point { int x; int y; ... }

List<Point> Points = new List<Point>()
{ 
  new Point(1,2), 
  new Point(3,4) 
};
```

I would like to convert this list to a flat `XElement` using single constructor (in one go).

What I want to see:

```
<Points>
  <x>1</x>
  <y>2</y>
  <x>3</x>
  <y>4</y>
</Points>
```

The furthest I got so far:

```
new XElement("Points",
  Points.Select(a => new {
    X = new XElement("x", a.x),
    Y = new XElement("y", a.y)
  });
```

Which produces a nested list, parsed as a single `XElement`.

```
<Points>{ X = <x>1</x>, Y = <y>2</y> }{ X = <x>3</x>, Y = <y>4</y> }</Points>
```

(I need to preserve the order so union wouldn't work)

I want to do everything in the constructor, like above, and **don't want** to manually add points like so:

```
XElement PointsXml = new XElement("Points");
foreach (var item in Points)
{
  PointsXml.Add(item.x);
  PointsXml.Add(item.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work:

```
var xml= new XElement("Points", 
    Points.SelectMany(a => new [] { new XElement("x", a.x), new XElement("y", a.y)}));
```

Or if you'd like to wrap each point in its own element then:

```
var xml= new XElement("Points", 
    Points.Select(a => 
        new XElement("Point", new XElement("x", a.x), new XElement("y", a.y))));
```

The trick is to always add objects of `XElement`.
The code you used will retrun an `anonymous object` and not this XElement array that is needed

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! Also, `Points.Select(a => new [] ...` worked too.